# Preventing properties from being added to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I basically just want to know if there's some standardized way to prevent methods/properties from being added to a JavaScript object?

As a c++ programmer it seems like you could end up with a lot of headaches trying to debug JavaScript code when it lets you add properties to an object on the fly, especially in large code bases.

Comment: Well, that's JS for ya :-)

Comment: If you're really just trying to prevent or detect accidental typing issues with a wrong property name assignment (as one of your comments suggests) on all your objects, then Javascript really doesn't support that and is generally not consistent with how you generally use Javascript. As has been said elsewhere, you can use `Object.freeze()`, `Object.seal()`, but that will likely get in the way of normal object operation.  If you're dying for this feature, then perhaps you'd rather use something like TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is sort-of, the ES5.1 [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) function can prevent new properties from being added, as well as prevent existing properties from changing.

## Working Example:

```js
var o = {
  a: 123
};
o.b = 456;

// Freeze the object.
Object.freeze(o);

// Log the object.
console.log(o);

// These do nothing, properties do not change and are not added.
o.b = 0;
o.c = 789;

// Log the object.
console.log(o);
```

That being said, JavaScript is a super dynamic language, so doing this extensively might be considered an anti-pattern.

If freeze is too limiting, other options include [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions), and [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), depending on what you wish to prevent.

Alternately [ES6 Proxy objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) can offer more control over which properties can be added or modified.

Comment: Ah right sorry, I might of explained my question a little strangely. I guess looking at the other responses what i'm after isn't really possible.                             In all honesty, I don't think that the code ambiguity problem i'm reffering to is that big of deal, atleast just for me on personal projects, but I can see there being some pretty horrible to find errors in large code bases when people say something like: car.age=3; car.Age=4; log(car.age)

Comment: You might also like object.seal() and /or object.preventExtensions()

Comment: @JonSG Good call, I forgot about them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There's probably ways to configure objects you don't want to be able to just attach new properties to, but nothing practical or standardized. Being primarily a javascript developer I don't find this to be an issue. I believe typescript does something for this with interfaces where it'll throw a warning if you start attaching properties it doesn't expect. A lot of javascript developers aren't a fan of this, but you might want to give it a try https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html